# Postgres 10.0 upsert syntax error not sure what to google for

Tags: postgresql, syntax, upsert

Postgres 10.0

table:

```
pcr=> \d tableFindOld
                               Table "public.tablefindold"
  Column  |            Type             | Collation | Nullable |         Default
----------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+-------------------------
 hostname | character varying(16)       |           | not null |
 lastmiss | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 lastfind | timestamp without time zone |           |          |
 uname    | character varying(64)       |           |          | NULL::character varying
Indexes:
    "tablefindold_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (hostname)
```

upsert statement:

```
INSERT INTO tableFindOld(hostname, lastMiss, lastFind, uname) 
VALUES('pcname', DEFAULT, '2019-03-04 11:38:04', 'billy') 
ON CONFLICT (tableFindOld.hostname) 
    DO UPDATE SET lastFind='2019-03-04 11:38:04', uname='billy' 
    WHERE tableFindOld.hostname='pcname';
```

error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ")"
LINE 1: ...8:04', 'billy') ON CONFLICT (tableFindOld.hostname) DO UPDAT...
                                                             ^
```

I have tried googling this to no avail. A few questions:

- What is the specific error here? (Really asking **Why** am I getting this error?)
- In upsert statements, for a column conflict condition (in this example it is the primary key conflict) is the column name supposed to be enclosed in parantheses or not? I have seen some inconsistent info on this.
- In an upsert statment with an update, are we supposed to include the `DO` keyword or not? Also have seen inconsistent info on this.

Also, I created the table with `DEFAULT NULL` on all columns except the primary key, so I'm not sure why that's not reflected in the description.

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:
Here is my table creation code:

```
CREATE TABLE tableFindOld(
    hostname VARCHAR(16) PRIMARY KEY,
    lastMiss TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
    lastFind TIMESTAMP DEFAULT NULL,
    uname VARCHAR(64) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

SOLUTION:
Thanks to McNets for this answer. For reference, the working statement:

```
INSERT INTO tableFindOld(hostname, lastMiss, lastFind, uname) VALUES('pcname', DEFAULT, '2019-03-04 12:30:04', 'billy') ON CONFLICT (hostname) DO UPDATE SET lastFind='2019-03-04 12:30:04', uname='billy' WHERE tableFindOld.hostname='pcname';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove table name in:

```
ON CONFLICT (hostname)
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=33e3fb38069ffaa6b1cb34e135fcbc1d)*

Quoted from docs:

[ON CONFLICT Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)

```
[ ON CONFLICT [ conflict_target ] conflict_action ]
```

> conflict_target can perform unique index inference. When performing inference, it consists of one or more **index_column_name** columns and/or **index_expression** expressions, and an optional **index_predicate**. All **table_name** unique indexes that, without regard to order, contain exactly the conflict_target-specified columns/expressions are inferred (chosen) as arbiter indexes.

Comment: McNets, thanks so much. I tried without table name before but I must have had a separate error. Thanks also for the dbfiddle link. I will bookmark that.